# How to get all facebook friends(who even not using the app) using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Im using facebook graph api to login to facebook and get all my friends names and ids, but im just getting those friends who are also using my app.

I want the list of all my existing friends whether or not using my app.

Please help!!

Comment: Seems facebook does not allow non app user friends to be listed in friends list...
But need some confirmation in favour or against my comment.
Thanx :)

Comment: @user3349709 Hey did you get any success on this?

Answer (score 1):

In v2.0 of the Graph API, calling `/me/friends` returns the person's friends who also use the app.

In addition, in v2.0, you must request the `user_friends` permission from each user. `user_friends` is no longer included by default in every login. Each user must grant the `user_friends` permission in order to appear in the response to `/me/friends`. See [the Facebook upgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids) for more detailed information, or review the summary below.

If you want to access a list of non-app-using friends, there are two options:

1. **[If you want to let your people tag their friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends)** in stories that they publish to Facebook using your App, you can use the `/me/taggable_friends` API. [Use of this endpoint requires review by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends) and should only be used for the case where you're rendering a list of friends in order to let the user tag them in a post.
2. **[If your App is a Game AND your Game supports Facebook Canvas](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends)**, you can use the `/me/invitable_friends` endpoint in order to render [a custom invite dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.0), then pass the tokens returned by this API to [the standard Requests Dialog.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0)

In other cases, apps are no longer able to retrieve the full list of a user's friends (only those friends who have specifically authorized your app using the `user_friends` permission). [This has been confirmed by Facebook as 'by design'.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396/)

For apps wanting allow people to invite friends to use an app, you can still use the [Send Dialog on Web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) or the new [Message Dialog on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/message-dialog/) and [Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/message-dialog/).